# Create a class in Codelite

Tags: c++, codelite

I'm trying to create a class in codelite 13.0.0, on Ubuntu 20 and i right click on src, but no choice appears for creating new class. I also work on Code Lite i can't remember version, on Ubuntu 18 and there I can create class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. You need the codelite plugins. Here there are the instruction on how you can install it. https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/codelite-plugins

After the installation, you restart the program, right click on the `src` folder, then `Add a new class`.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are:

1. Click on New Workspace
2. Select “C++” as the workspace type
3. Name your workspace

Comment: I did all these thing.

Comment: Come on man, I'm asking how create a new class not a project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Wizards` plugin.
Go to `Plugins`, then `Manage Plugins...`, then activate `Wizards` and restart CodeLite.
After that you can create a class from `Plugins > Wizards > New Class Wizard`